# Expectations are failing in iOS Unit Test

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following test, which checks for multiple expectations to be fulfilled. But for some reason this test is always failing. I am guessing that my notifications are not firing.

```
class when_posting_two_alerts: XCTestCase {

    func test_generates_two_notifications() {

        let alertManager = AlertManager()

        let exp = expectation(forNotification: Notification.Name.alertNotification, object: alertManager, handler: nil)
        exp.expectedFulfillmentCount = 2

        alertManager.postAlert()
        alertManager.postAlert()

        wait(for: [exp], timeout: 1)
```

AlertManager is implemented below:

```
import Foundation

class AlertManager {

    func postAlert() {
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name.alertNotification, object: nil)
    }
}


extension Notification.Name {

    static let alertNotification = Notification.Name("alertPostedNotification")

}
```

Any ideas why the test keeps on failing?

Comment: I am just testing for two for learning purposes. From the code above it should post two notifications since I called postAlert twice.

Comment: I checked again and the looks like Notifications are just not fired at all.

Comment: Found the solution:  NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name.alertNotification, object: self)